Neutron detection efficiency in plastic scintillators
What is an estimate of the detection efficiency of incoming neutrons with kinetic energies of 150MeV and 200MeV for an 'average' multi-purpose plastic scintillator per cm of material depth?
Obviously, this depends on the specific setup, meaning also the light guides, photomultipliers, cluster threshold settings etc. . This is why I am only searching for a rough estimate.
I find it hard to come by data for fast neutrons. One source I found is this, figure 3.(a), estimating ~18% detection efficiency in a 15,24cm deep plastic scintillator for 150MeV neutrons.
Many thanks in advance.

I think 18 percent is the rough estimate. Do you have any estimate of how long (mean free path wise) a neutron takes to stop in plastic, and how many scintillation photons there are? (Like order of magnitude--I had an air-Cherenkov that average 6 photons, and scintillators that made thousands per event....js.)

(+1) @JEB Would left-handed neutrons leave any difference in their tracks/signatures compared to right-handed neutrons in the scintillator?

@james Unless the scintillator is somehow spin polarized, that's a part per billion parity violation experiment.

@rob I worked on SAMPLE at MIT-Bates (P.V. in $\vec e(p, p)e$) a long time ago, and it was 'just' a part per million , irrc. Also, I've been to seminars describing final state neutron polarimeters, but I do not know how they work.

@JEB Polarimetry requires that your analyzer have some known polarization. SAMPLE was a good experiment; let's grab a beer sometime.

When a $150-200$ MeV neutron interacts inelastically with the hydrogen and carbon nuclei in plastic scintillator,  it will almost always produce charged particles (protons, alphas, recoil nuclei). (See, for example,  the first figure in this answer to "Energy-dependent neutron cross section data".)  These charged particles will produce more than enough scintillation light to be easily detected, so the neutron detection efficiency ($\epsilon$) can simply be estimated from the neutron inelastic absorption length ($\lambda$) and thickness ($t$) of the scintillator, i.e.
$$\epsilon \sim 1-e^{-t/\lambda}$$
According to the Review of Particle Properties table of Atomic and Nuclear Properties of Materials,  $\lambda_I\sim 80\ \mathrm{g/cm^2}$ and $\rho\sim 1.2\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$ for the typical base plastics (e.g. acrylic) used for solid plastic scintilators, so the absorption length in centimetres will be $\lambda \sim 80/1.2\sim67$ cm.
The detection efficiency for $150-200$ MeV neutrons by a $t=15.24$ cm thick scintillator is hence expected to be $\epsilon\sim 1-e^{-15.24/67}= 20\%$, in good agreement with the $\sim18$% from the source you found.
For another check, according to Figure 4b of "Improved predictions of neutron detection efficiency for hydrocarbon scintillators from 1 MeV to about 300 MeV", the detection efficiency for $150-200$ neutrons in $45$ cm thick NE-224 liquid scintillator is just under $40$%. NE-224 has a lower density of $0.877\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$, so $\lambda \sim 80/0.877\sim91$ cm, and the expected efficiency for a $t=45$ cm thickness will be $\epsilon\sim 1-e^{-45/91}\sim 39\%$, again in excellent agreement with the observed efficiency.

Great answer, many thanks.
